# problem with weight paint

Tags: weight-painting

I am beginner in blender,

I want to make grass and move them in one side of the plane with weight paint but it does not work and sometimes it works but it painted the both sides of the plane.

[image]

[image]

I use blender2.81
and I instaled the last version of blender , but it does not work.
what is wrong?
[image]

Comment: do you have enough vertices?

Comment: yes but I have problem with the weight paint mode.

Comment: If you have modifiers on that plane, please add a screenshot and it would help if you could add a picture of the weight paint.

Comment: as you can see in the pictures , it is in the weight paint mode.I do not understand the first sentence.

Comment: Ok, my bad, but i was expecting some coloration on the plane, though now i wonder more about which object you have selected at the time of the picture, since the outliner does not show any active object. The first sentence is regarding a possible modifier on the plane with the particle system. That said, if you do not mind, i'd suggest to share the file using [Blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so a closer look could be taken to easier find the issue.

Comment: ok.I added the blend file.maybe the number of vortices are few.sorry my english is not my first language:)

Comment: the problem has been solved :)

Comment: I updated my answer based on the file you shared. If you found a solution, i would though in the future encourage you to share that if others solutions did not solve it. That way the question can be considered closed and others with similar situations can follow the answer to hopefully solve their situation too.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated based on the shared file:**

I believed your grass had the origin in the middle and thus when distributing it on the plane made them stick through the plane to the other side, using the file shared as source, here the *first* **two** problems:
[image]
*(marked red, the origin in the center as mentioned already, BUT also the not applied scale, which will always result in unwanted results)*

The resulting grass looking like what i believed before i got the file to work on:
[image]

Solution:

1. Select the grass object
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to reset the position to origin, making the next step easier
   [image]
3. Go in edit mode and select all with <kbd>A</kbd>
   [image]
4. Move the vertices of the grass so that it's lowest vertex sits on the origin (on meaning in the same z/height coordinates)
   [image]
5. To ensure that the grass object is scaled correctly we also apply the rotation and scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> "Rotation & Scale".
6. Finally there is the need to generate the **weight map**, but for that to be possible, you need to have some subdivisions on the plane, as otherwise the entire plane can only have each corner weighted.
7. Subdivide the plane with the particle system on by pressing <kbd>RMB</kbd> and choosing "Subdivide", now you can either press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+R to repeat that a few times, or open the little pop up at the bottom left and adjust the amount of subdivisions in one go.
   [image]
8. Now with enough subdivisions, go in **weight paint** mode and paint the area the grass is supposed to be:
   [image]

After those steps and activating the visibility of the particle system, i get the following:
[image]

That said, you may have wanted smaller grass, you can scale it down in object mode.
[image]
Though i would recommend to scale in edit mode or at least to apply the scale afterwards again, having the origin at the right place then also makes sure that the grass scales properly.

Happy Blending

Comment: no it does not work.

Comment: What exactly does not work @amirka?

Comment: @brockmann thanks to your comment i found out that there was a file shared. Updated my answer corresponding and even though my answer already pointed to one of the problem, it sure was not the only one. Hope it's now more encompassing for similar cases.

Answer (score 1):

This because of normals, in edit mode press shift + n to recalculate them.
edit:then try extruding your plane very slightly and remove all weight paint except for the upper plane.

Comment: no it does not work.

Comment: What exactly does not work @amirka?